# In R, what does byrow do exactly?

Tags: r

I am new to R. I understand if for instance I have a matrix I am interested in building:

```r
a <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), nrow=2)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    3    5    7
# [2,]    2    4    6    8
```

what exactly does byrow do differently in the example below? that is what I am having difficulty understanding

```r
a <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), nr=2, byrow = T)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4
# [2,]    5    6    7    8
```

Comment: It fills the matrix _row_-wise whereas default is column-wise.

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf.